# React-select not clearing current selection and allowing null to be selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, api, react-select

I am sure this is simple yet I have been at it for hours...
I have a react-select element and I can add or edit and update but cannot figure out how to clear the select and set the DB field to null.

**Component**

```
          selectPriority(priority) {
        this.updateAttribute("priorityId", priority.value)
        this.updateAttribute("priority", priority.label)
        }
```

**Select Element**

```
        <Select
        name="select_priority"
        value={proposalService.priorityId ? proposalService.priorityId 
              : null}
        options={priorities.map(p => ({
           value: p.id,
           label: p.name,
            }))
          .sort((a, b) => a.label < b.label)}
        onChange={p => this.selectPriority(p) || null}
        placeholder="Select Priority"
        />
```

**Console Error when clicking "X" in React-Select element**

```
ProposalServiceForm.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at ProposalServiceForm.selectPriority (ProposalServiceForm.js:86)
at Object.onChange (ProposalServiceForm.js:342)
at Object.setValue (Select.js:683)
at Object.clearValue (Select.js:748)
at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js:69)
at executeDispatch (EventPluginUtils.js:85)
at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (EventPluginUtils.js:105)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (EventPluginHub.js:43)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (EventPluginHub.js:54)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're clicking the 'x', you're sending null to the selectPriority() function, rather than an object.  The error is telling you that null does not have the property 'value' (nor does it have label).

The simplest solution would be to test for null in the function then assign it:

```
selectPriority(priority) {
    this.updateAttribute("priorityId", priority ? priority.value : null)
    this.updateAttribute("priority", priority  ? priority.label : null)
  }
```

Or:

```
selectPriority(priority) {
  if (priority == null) {
    this.updateAttribute("priorityId", null)
    this.updateAttribute("priority", null)
  } else {
    this.updateAttribute("priorityId", priority.value)
    this.updateAttribute("priority", priority.label)
  }
}
```